# Possibility for Flyway to split V1__*.sql file into multi files like V1__1.sql, V1__2.sql

Tags: sql-server, flyway

I need to set up a new database with more than 50 tables, naturally, they can be divided into several groups:

1. Group1 for some tables with common data.
2. Group2 for tables that express one same domain context.
3. Group3 for tables that express another same domain context.

Each group will be described as a separate SQL file and should be executed following the above order.
Since it is the very beginning of initiating a database, I should version them all to V1.

It is something like this:

- V1__group1.sql
- V1__group2.sql
- V1__group3.sql

Or with a directory named V1:

V1/

```
group1.sql
group2.sql
group3.sql
```

They are all versioned by V1, group1.sql will be executed before group2.sql and group2.sql will be executed before group3.sql.

**With Flyway, can I get this achieved?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this.

- The primary option is `V1__` for group one, `v2__` for group two etc.
- Secondly, you can have more finely grained version numbers like `v1.1` for group one, `v1.2` for group 2. Flyway is very flexible with its version numbers supporting multiple parts, such as `v1.1.0.68'. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#versioned-migrations for more details.

It is worth noting as well, that there is no technical reason to keep the database setup to version 1;
While the names like V1__ and V2__ sound like they mean "version 1" and "version 2", that's not quite true. It is actually the concatenation of two things, the type of script  (versioned) and then the sequence number (not the version number); V1 is the first `versioned` script, V2 is the second `versioned` script.
Scripts will be run in the order defined by their version number.

Comment: Yeah, I'd use the V1.1 method to set this up if you really want to keep the scripts apart.

Comment: @madninja , thank you, great to know Flyway can do it at all. Thanks to the explanation of versioned migration, I just know V1 is not a "version 1". That is enlightening.

Comment: @Grant Fritchey, yes, agree. That would be a good practice.